# Django Regular expression many slugs

Tags: python, regex, django

I have the regular expression in my url that accepts pass one slug to my view, exemple:

> 127.0.0.1/cart/product_slug1

But I need a regex that accept pass one or more slugs, example:

> 127.0.0.1/cart/product_slug1/product_slug2/product_slug3/.../product_slugN

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(
    r'^cart/add/(?P<slug>[\w_-]+)/$', views.create_cartitem,
    name='create_cartitem'
),
```

It's possible send many slugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**: It seems that you cannot do that. Instead, you can place a catch all pattern and capture the whole url. Then inside your `views` you can split it by `/` and get the parameters you want. Something like this:

```
 urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^cart/add/(?P<slugs>[\w_/-]+)/$', views.create_cartitem, name='create_cartitem'
    ),
```

And then in your `views`, do this:

```
def my_view(request, slugs):
    slugs = slugs.split('/')
    # now slugs is a list of strings
```

Note, however, that this is error prone since both `cart/add/h/e/l/l/o` and `cart/add/hell//o//to/you` are valid.

-- OLD ANSWER --

Sure you can, but you cannot use [both named captured parameters with unnamed ones](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#the-matching-grouping-algorithm).

So, change your `urls.py` to this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^cart/add/([\w_-]+)/([\w_-]+/)*$', views.create_cartitem, name='create_cartitem'
    ),
```

And inside your `views.py`, instead of `kwargs` (like `slug` you already have) you must use `args` (positional arguments, now you're gonna have a list of `slug`s). Like this:

```
def my_view(request, *args):
    for arg in args:
        print(arg)
```

Now if you type `127.0.0.1:8000/cart/add/argv/argvv/argvvv/`, inside your `views` you get them as a list `['argv', 'argvv', 'argvvv']`.

Comment: Thanks, works when I pass two args. But, when I pass just one arg and print args on the view return this: ['arg1', none]

Comment: Yes, that's the price you have to pay, though. But I see no problem to that. Simple handle all not `None` values and ignore the others.